# How to get div and full inner content in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want get div inner content in javascript

Ex:

```
<div id="content" style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden">
  content<br>content<br>content<br>
</div>
```

This is my html code. i know only div id (content). but i want retrieved main div and their inner content via javascript like..

```
<div id="content" style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden">
 content<br>content<br>content<br>
</div>
```

Also i want retrieved content div attribute also like style, class name etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getElementById()` to get the element and `innerHTML` to get tht content

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
```

[LIVE DEMO FOR INNERHTML](http://jsfiddle.net/TQaRJ/)

To get the content of the whole tag , use `outerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('content').outerHTML;
```

[LIVE DEMO FOR OUTERHTML](http://jsfiddle.net/TQaRJ/2/)

Comment: Its ok . but i want content div attribute also like style, class name etc.                                                                    <div id="content" style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden">

Comment: See my edited post .. You can use outerHTML to get the attributes of your div

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the content that is inside the div, you can use `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML`. This will return

```
content<br>content<br>content<br>
```

But if you want to retrieve the html with div tags included, you can try using `document.getElementById("contents").outerHTML`. This will return you

```
<div id="content" style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden">
 content<br>content<br>content<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this piece of code to retrieve inner content

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
```