# How can I get the text from the div, this way?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use javascript.
Before the br I have text too, which changes. It can be 4/20, or 10/20 etc.

```js
var questionString = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].innerText;


console.log(questionString)
```

```html
<DIV class="question">1/20
  <BR>THIS IS A QUESTION?</DIV>
```

Comment: What is the current result of questionString, and what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: Will be much easier if you wrap the number inside a `span`

Comment: Your exemple works no? I don't understand

Comment: I can't modify the page, i want to build to my userscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get div and full inner content in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826349/how-to-get-div-and-full-inner-content-in-javascript)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i want to get the question :D

Comment: the div contains "the question" **and** `1/20` so what you want is not the content of the div is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your question.

```js
var questionString = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].innerHTML.split('<br>')[1];
console.log(questionString)
```

```html
<DIV  class="question">1/20<BR>THIS IS A QUESTION?</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the questions after the BR, try this:

```js
let qs = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".question").forEach((d) =>
  qs.push(d.innerText.replace(/\d{1,}\/\d{1,}\s+/, ""))
)
console.log(qs)
```

```html
<DIV class="question">1/20
  <BR>THIS IS QUESTION 1 of 20</DIV>
<DIV class="question">2/20
  <BR>THIS IS QUESTION 2 of 20</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

By 4/20 you mean the current question is the 4th question among a total of 20 questions, right?
I believe that your requirement is when the user click next button, you want the text "4/20" to change into "5/20".

```js
// have a reference to the question text's DOM
var question_no_dom = document.getElementById("question_no");
var question_dom = document.getElementById("question");
// list of questions
var questions = ["1. How tall is mount everest?",
                "2. What is the capital city of Russia?", 
                "3. How far way is the sun from the earth?"];
// start with the first question
var current_quest_no = 0;
var total_no_quest = 3

question_no_dom.innerText = (current_quest_no+1)+'/'+total_no_quest;
question_dom.innerText = questions[current_quest_no];

function onNext() {
  if(current_quest_no < total_no_quest-1) {
    current_quest_no++;
    question_no_dom.innerText =   (current_quest_no+1)+'/'+total_no_quest;
  question_dom.innerText = questions[current_quest_no];
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="question_no"></div><br>
<div id="question"></div><br>
<button onclick="onNext()">Next&nbsp;></button>
```

Comment: That is likely NOT what he wanted

Answer (score -4):

Grab the first child node of the div (which given your html will always be your desired text node) then trim it to remove the extra spacing and newline.

```js
var questionString = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].childNodes[0].textContent.trim()


console.log(questionString)
```

```html
<DIV class="question">1/20
  <BR>THIS IS A QUESTION?</DIV>
```

Comment: It is likely the second part he wanted